# nftables: usage ct label set in

Tags: nftables

Using in statefull mode, I collect information about the amount of packages/bytes from the rules and do not create the rules for returning packages because they are accepted based on the states stored in the conntrack "ct state established", that is, I cannot get the information from the return traffic. In order not to need to create an inverse rule for the packet just to for collect this information, I intend to insert a label for each rule to collect this information using conters nomed.

Then the question arises:
How to add label on conntrack in nftables rule?

In [man](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/nftables/nft.8.en.html#CONNTRACK_STATEMENT) there is no example set label in conntrack.

Answer (score 0):

In file /etc/nftables/connlabel.conf:

> 0 foo

Create counter:

```
nft add counter filter input_enp2s0
```

---

In my table mangle:

```
nft add rule ip mangle prerouting iif enp2s0 ct label set foo
nft add rule ip filter forward iif enp2s0 ct label foo counter name input_enp2s0
```